# Accents not working on LibreOffice. How to report bug

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice

When I try to write an accent (spanish in my case) in Libre Office, it just won't write it. I know everything else is fine since I can write accents on other programs (i.e my console). 
What is curious is that I can write accents (í ó ú) until I click somewhere else, lets say, I open firefox or I do something in KUbuntu. Then, if I start working in LibreOffice again, I can't write accents anymore.

So, if this is a bug, where should I report it?

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 KDE the solution was editing `/etc/default/locale` and change `LANGUAGE` to `pt_PT.UTF-8` keeping all the other values and rebooting.

Comment: I was having thins problem on KDE Neon, using e_CA.UTF-8 and fr_CA.UTF-8 locales, and the Canadian multilingual keyboard. Launching Libreoffice from the command line gave me these warnings: I18N: Operating system doesn't support locale "" I18N: Operating system doesn't support locale "en_US" I don't have any idea what the en_US locale has to do with accented characters, but building the en_US ISO-8859-1 locale fixed the problem for me (I had only built en_US.UTF-8). To do this on a debian or ubuntu based distro, run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and select en_US ISO-8859-1 as well as any other lo

Answer (score 1):

The issue is discussed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/451840/accents-stop-working-all-of-a-sudden-in-libreoffice . It does seem to occur when combining a few different packages. Therefore the LibreOffice bug tracker is probably not the best place, but the bug tracker of your distribution.

There exists a bug here as well:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71437

The solution proposed there

```
unset XMODIFIERS && libreoffice
```

was the one which worked for me on `kubuntu`.  I also had to generate the locale `en_US` (libreoffice printed an error message that it did not exist).

Answer (score 0):

I would report this bug through Libre Office's [Bug Submission Assistant](https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/bug/).

> Thank you for using LibreOffice and for helping us improve our software. This assistant will lead you step-by-step through the bug-reporting process. Please submit a separate bug for each issue!
>   For our full-featured bugtracker go to [bugs.libreoffice.org](http://bugs.libreoffice.org/)